# Why do webkit and mozilla size flex box differently?

Tags: html, css, webkit, mozilla, flexbox

I've left out coloring and such, but the idea that I'm after is a 1000px wide (980 with padding) header block no taller than 125px, with a 15% wide logo block on the left (containing a clickable image that resizes to fit), a title block and nav block in the second, 85% wide column. The logo block extends six pixels beyond the bottom of the nav block (due to the nav block's 6px bottom margin.) The whole header block winds up 10px above the main block.

Example can be seen here: http://www.bsu.edu/academy/test/

In Firefox, it does what it's supposed to. My img winds up 147px wide and 124px tall, and the header block expands to fit it and it winds up 10px above the main block. So the logo block is defining the height of the header flexbox.

In Chrome, the title block and nav block shrink to fit their content, the logo block is the correct size, but overlaps the main block, which is 16px above the main block. (6px nav margin, 10px main margin). So title and nav are defining the height of the header flexbox.

Which of these is behaving correctly, and how do I get both of them to behave the way mozilla is?

Here is a rough version of the layout I'm trying to work with:

```
<header>
    <div id="logo"><a href=""><img src="" /></a></div>
    <div id="title><h1>Title</h1></div>
    <nav>Navigation</nav>
</header>
<main>Content</main>
```

And the relevant parts of the CSS I'm trying to work with:

```
header {
    display:-webkit-flex; display:flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow:column wrap; flex-flow:column wrap;
    max-width:1000px;
    width:100%;
    max-height:125px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 10px;
    }

#logo {
    display:-webkit-flex; display:flex;
    max-width:148px;
    width:15%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

    #logo a {
        display:-webkit-flex; display:flex;
        border:none;
        height:auto;
        }

    img {
        display:block;
        border:none;
        width:100%;
        margin:auto;
        }

    #logo a img {padding:0 8px 8px 8px;}

#title {
    -webkit-flex:1 0 auto; flex:1 0 auto;
    display:-webkit-flex; display:flex;
    width:85%;
    }

nav {
    width:85%;
    margin:0 0 6px 0;
    }

main {margin-top:10px;}
```